# Python 3.x : UnboundLocalError and Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
words = []
words_needed = 0


def input_words():
    inputWords = input('Please input more words that you want to play with.').lower()
    words.append(inputWords)
    words_needed += 1
    while words_needed < 5:
        input_words()
    else:
        words_needed >= 5
        input_SS = input('Do you want to continue adding words?')
        if input_SS == 'yes':
            input_words()
        elif input_SS == 'no':
            end

def Start_up():
    start_question = input('Do you want to add your own words to the list?')
    if start_question == 'yes':
        input_words()
    elif start_question == 'no':
        pre_words = (*words in a list*)
        words.extend(pre_words)


Start_up()
```

When I run this segment of code it either runs off forever of brings me back an error of;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\A453\Code\Python Hangman\Hangman.py", line X, in <module>
    Start_up()
  File "F:\A453\Code\Python Hangman\Hangman.py", line Y, in Start_up
    input_words()
  File "F:\A453\Code\Python Hangman\Hangman.py", line Z, in input_words
    words_needed += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'words_needed' referenced before assignment
```

Im fairly new to coding so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain the problem to you

The problem is with the statement

```
words_needed += 1
```

It expands to

```
words_needed =  words_needed + 1
```

So it creates a local variable inside your function, however you are trying to access it's value when you are doing `words_needed + 1` and is thus throwing an error.

You have to options left

- **Standard and Accurate way.**
  Define your function as `def input_words(words_needed):` passing the `words_needed` as parameter and wherever you are calling the function call it as `input_words(words_needed)`
- **Bad and insecure way.**
  Add a line, `global words_needed` at the start of your `input_words` function

Comment: This question gives some more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 0):

When you call `words_needed+=1`, you are trying to access the variable `words_needed` in the **local** scope, where it is not defined. Therefore, you should pass in and return `words_needed`, so it is accessible everywhere:

```
words = []
words_needed = 0


def input_words(words_needed):
    inputWords = input('Please input more words that you want to play with.').lower()
    words.append(inputWords)
    words_needed += 1
    while words_needed < 5:
        input_words()
    else:
        words_needed >= 5
        input_SS = input('Do you want to continue adding words?')
        if input_SS == 'yes':
            input_words()
        elif input_SS == 'no':
            return words_needed
    return words_needed

def Start_up():
    start_question = input('Do you want to add your own words to the list?')
    if start_question == 'yes':
        words_needed = input_words(words_needed)
    elif start_question == 'no':
        pre_words = (["words", "in", "a", "list"])
        words.extend(pre_words)


Start_up()
```